# Regexp issue, Multiple matches but why?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this text:

Content before

```
[row marginTop="10" marginBottom="10"]

[column_3]

[column][article id="12" /][/column]

[column][article id="13" /][/column]

[column][article id="14" /][/column]

[/column_3]

[/row]
```

And when I do this:

```
$pattern = '/^(\[([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]+[a-zA-Z0-9]) *( [a-zA-Z]+(="[^".]*")?)*( *\/)?\])$/';
preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

print_r($matches);
```

The result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [row marginTop="10" marginBottom="10"]
            [1] => 137
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  marginBottom="10"
            [1] => 156
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => ="10"
            [1] => 166
        )

)
```

Why? And what could I do to avoid this?

Comment: And what was your expected output?

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [row marginTop="10" marginBottom="10"]
            [1] => 137
        )
)

Just this one.

Comment: Actualy I don't want to find matches on the subpatterns. Just the whole pattern. Sry for my bad english :\

Comment: offtopic, but you might be able to replace `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` with `\w` depending on the regex engine, the other ranges (`[...]`) also should have replacements

Comment: The regex engine is not fix, I'll be always different so I feel [a-zA-Z0-9_] is safe and "cross-compatible".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subpattern notation `(...)` serves two purposes: grouping, and capturing. So `$matches` ends up with the content of all your subpatterns, as well as the match as a whole.

If you don't want that, you can remove the parentheses you don't need for grouping, and in cases where you need grouping without capturing, you can use the *non-capturing subpattern* notation `(?:...)`:

```
$pattern = '/^\[[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]+[a-zA-Z0-9] *(?: [a-zA-Z]+(?:="[^".]*")?)*(?: *\/)?\]$/';
```

(See ["Subpatterns" in the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php) for more information.)